# Show Query Results with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching with no luck so sorry if this has been answered before.

I am wanting to show the results of the query with something like " Viewing 1-10 of 100" basically showing the current posts I am viewing and the total post count. If someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the following code in the file `search.php` or anywhere you need.

```
<?php
function get_number_of_results( $current_page, $total, $jumps = 10){
    $first_result = 1;
    $start = $first_result;
    $end = $jumps;

    if($current_page >=2) {
        $previous = $current_page - 1;
        $first_result = ($previous * $jumps) + 1;
        $start = $first_result;
        $end = $start + ($total - 1);
    }
    return "$start - $end";
}

$current_page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$total = $wp_query->post_count; 
// Result
echo "Viewing " . get_number_of_results( $current_page, $total); 
?>
```

**Notes**

- You can move the function to the file `functions.php` to just call the two las lines of my example.
- The line: `<?php $total = $wp_query->post_count; ?>` retrieve the number of total results.
- The variable `$current_page` retrieve the current page of the results ([more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)).
- The function can jump between the number of pages you only need to specify as third parameter.